# Text not showing at the left top of input box

Tags: html, css

The issue for one of my input boxes is that the text begins quite a bit further on the right instead of the top left as you can see on the image shown below.  I've already looked at similar topics but have been unable to still fix it.

```
<label for="content_field"><?php echo $this->__('Message') ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <textarea class="required-entry" name="content" id="content_field" cols="53" rows="100"
                style="width: 1035px; height: 200px;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($data->getContent()) ?>
            </textarea>
        </div>
```

css

```
.form-list input[type="text"], .my-account select, textarea, #discount-coupon-form input {
    width                 : 300px;
    height                : 22px;
    border                : 1px solid #bebcb7;
    -webkit-border-radius : 3px;
    -moz-border-radius    : 3px;
    border-radius         : 5px;
    margin                : 0;
    padding               : 3px 3px;
    color: #434343;
}

.form-list .input-box {
    display : block;
    clear   : both;
    width   : 260px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: sounds like you've got a text-indent in there somewhere put us up a fiddle to check it or paste a url :D

Comment: a link would be helpful... btw, have you tried removing the 'cols' and 'rows' attributes from the 'textarea' tag?

Comment: Is the text still indented after the first line? If not, it's most likely text-indent like @vimes1984 said, otherwise it could be inheriting padding.

Comment: Take everything out - try returning your style bit by bit and you will find the problem :)

Comment: I tried text-indent: 0px, took off cols and rows before creating this question and the website is not yet live to give you an example of it.

Comment: Can you select the indent? Could it be that `<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($data->getContent()) ?>` is inserting a bunch of spaces/tabs? Perhaps try removing that bit and see if it's still an issue - just as a test of course.

Comment: I've removed, and it's still indented.  I also created a blank input box right below the Message input box, and that input box is also indented.  However the Title input box works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fiddled your code and tried everything then realized that you literally have spaces between the end of your first textarea tag and the closing textarea tag. Remove the orange part I have highlighted.

[image: Imgur]

Or replace your code with:

```
<label for="content_field"><?php echo $this->__('Message') ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <textarea name="content" id="content_field"  cols="53" rows="100" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($data->getContent()) ?></textarea>
    </div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTk2T/5/